# How do i load() html with jquery more than once?

Tags: jquery, html, load, external

i use this code to load html to my container;

```
$('#button').click(function() {
$('#container').load("index.html");
    });
```

My question to you is, can i load the html multiple times to my container? If yes, how?
And if it's possible, isn't it heavy weighted to load?

index.html contains a div wich is draggable, able to toggle hide and show etc.

I want to load this html multiple times to a container in the body of another html page.

Hope you can help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're considering doing?

Comment: @lonesomeday i added some more info thank you

Comment: And what do you mean by "multiple times"? Can you give an example of code?

Comment: @lonesomeday well the code above loads the html only once onclick. But the code below from the answers makes it possible to load the html more than once so let's say i got a blue div in index html, and i click the button four times, the blue div appears four times in the container.

Comment: However, only the first onclick load is draggable and they all react to the same event handlers.. that wasnt my intention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code should work as you have it.  If `#button` is inside `#container` it will be removed though, so you can't press the button again.  Either move the button outside of container or use `.live()` to have the click event always bind to `#button`, even when it is replaced.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

If you want to append to  `#container`, use something like this:

```
$.get('index.html', function(data) {
    $('#container').append(data);
});
```

Comment: thank you the button is outside the container, if i use live() what would be the benefits of that? would be faster?

Comment: live was only for if the button was inside the container.  what it does is make sure that anything with the selector you pass to it has the event you supply - now and in the future.  so if the button was in the container and got deleted when you replaced the content, the live method would make it have the click functionality still

Answer (score 2):

The [$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function is equivalent to:

```
$.get('index.html', function(data) {
  $('#container').html(data);
});
```

Which is to say, the `innerHTML` of `#container` will be overwritten with each call to `$.load()`. It sounds to me like you want to do:

```
$.get('index.html', function(data) {
  $('#container').append(data);
});
```

Comment: thank you it works perfectly, is there a way though how i can make the appended html more individual because they all respond to each others event handlers :p

Comment: That's a design flaw and a different question in my opinion.